# Can't compute the Polymer iron-ajax headers property before request is done

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to generate a Iron-Ajax request after adding a user token programmatically to the headers property of the iron-ajax element. The problem is that the console returns me a 401 (Unauthorized). However, I am certain that the token is right and the problem must be the way I am implementing it.
For testing purposes I log the token after retrieving it from the iron-storage and I log the return that my compute function should be binding to the headers property of the iron-ajax. All the results I get returned in the console are right. In addition the whole process works when I hardcode the token inside the headers of the iron-ajax. This is why I am sure the problem comes from the somewhere else. I create the request now after computing the headers property instead of setting auto on the iron-ajax because I figured the problem might be that the compute function might be executed after the request is already done. However I cant get it to work.
I hope someone can point me in the direction where my error is.

```
<dom-module id="my-newsfeed-view">
  <template>

    <iron-ajax
      id="requestNews"
      url="http://api.mjp.dev/v1/news/"
      handle-as="json"
      headers='{{header}}'
      loading="{{isloading}}"
      last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
    is: 'my-newsfeed-view',

    properties: {
      user: {
        type: String,
      },
      header: {
        computed: 'computeHeader(user)'
      },

    },

    ready: function() {
      // Get User key from the Storage
      this.$.localstorage.reload();
      // console.log('This token is:' + this.user.token);

      this.computeHeader();
      // console.log('{"Authorization": "Bearer ' + this.user.token + '"}');
      this.$.requestNews.generateRequest();
    },

    computeHeader: function(user) {
      return '{"Authorization": "Bearer ' + this.user.token + '"}';
    },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is `computeHeader()` is returning a `string` when it should return an `Object`. `<iron-ajax>` will automatically deserialize the `Object`, and merge it into the request headers. It should look like this:

```
computeHeader: function(user) {
  return {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.token};
}
```

You also don't need to call `computeHeader()` inside `ready()`.

The second problem is that `this.user` is a `string`, which is passed to `computeHeader(user)`, which assumes its `user` argument is an object that contains `token`. It's unclear how `user` is set in your code, but you might consider adding a `token` property that could replace `user` in `computeHeader(token)`.

Demo:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      headers: {
        computed: '_computeHeader(token)'
      },
      token: {
        type: String,
        value: '1234'
      }
    },
    _computeHeader: function(token) {
      return {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token};
    },
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      console.log('response', e.detail.response);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax auto headers="[[headers]]" url="https://httpbin.org/get" on-response="_onResponse"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bwkvdP?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks @tony19 !
I don't even know why I changed the type of the user property to String instead of Object. However, it works with both for some reason. The way I computed my Header was the main issue i guess